# How to increase a value in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jbutton, jtextfield

I have `JTextField` and I want to increase the value by adding one (+1) every time the `JButton` is pressed.

```
public void addtoj()
{
    String m = jTextField1.getText();
    int addone = Integer.valueOf(s);
    s = Integer.toString(++addone);
    jTextField1.setText(m);
}
```

Comment: I think you are getting confused by your `m` and `s`.

Comment: Use more descriptive variable names to help avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: Why don't you try `accepting` answers from your previous questions first before asking new question. Don't you know the basic concept of saying "thank you" when someone spends the time to help you?

Comment: hi camickr I appreciate the help that I received before, but I didnt get an answer for my previous question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, then it should be `s` not `m`, like so -

```
String s = jTextField1.getText(); // <-- s not m.
int addone = Integer.valueOf(s);
s = Integer.toString(++addone);
jTextField1.setText(s); // <-- s not m.
```

Or maybe it should be,

```
String m = jTextField1.getText();
int addone = Integer.valueOf(m);
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(addone+1));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void addtoj()
{
    String text = jTextField1.getText();        

    int value = Integer.parseInt(text); 

    value = value + 1;      

    text = Integer.toString(value); 

    jTextField1.setText(text);
}
```

Or

```
public void addtoj()
{
    jTextField1.setText(
        Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()) + 1 ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you well if I didn't please forgive me
to make it :
in ActionListenerclass write this:

```
float s = (float) Double.parseDouble(theTextField.getText());
int counter = 0;
counter++;
theTextField.setText("" + counter);
```